# Huffman code decoder - send a dictionary of encoder

Tags: java

Hi I'm a computer science student - in my second year. During my studies, they let me do a project. Build the Hoffman code. Much of the code I built and it works well for me. But I barely got stuck, the encoder I built well, but the decoder is causing me problems.

The encoding works properly. Encoding is done according to a dictionary per character. Decoding also needs this dictionary. My question is how can I pass the dictionary to the decoder - without changing the signatures of the original functions.

My difficulty is to implement the decoder - without changing the 4 functions set by the lecturer. I can add as many functions as I want - as long as the structure remains the same - for the original 4 functions.

The encoder - receives a file - and converts it into bytes - in compression. It goes over the original file, counts the number of impressions per character, and then builds a tree with code for each character.

The decoder - need to get the tree - to convert the bytes to the original file - here I got stuck. How do I send from the encoder the tree for the decoder.

The code has predefined classes and functions - according to the lecturer's instructions. I will not be able to change the signatures to functions. However, I may create some and what functions I want.

Non-changeable functions:

```
public class HuffmanEncoderDecoder implements Compressor
{

    public HuffmanEncoderDecoder()
    {
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    }

    @Override
    public void Compress(String[] input_names, String[] output_names)
    {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    @Override
    public void Decompress(String[] input_names, String[] output_names)
    {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    @Override
    public byte[] CompressWithArray(String[] input_names, String[] output_names)
    {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public byte[] DecompressWithArray(String[] input_names, String[] output_names)
    {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return null;
    }

}
```

The code I already implemented

```
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        String[] input_names = {"C:\\Documents\\files-huffman\\check.txt"};
        String[] output_names = {"C:\\Documents\\files-huffman\\out.txt"};
        HuffmanEncoderDecoder objectHuffman = new HuffmanEncoderDecoder();
        objectHuffman.Compress(input_names, output_names);
        //how to send to the objectHuffman.Decompress the tree or the map of codes
```

the check.txt contain : abra cadabra
the out.txt contain : 0110111010101011010001101110

I only built the first function that encodes the file. And auxiliary functions that help me encode - such as a function that counts a number of characters in the input file and a function that builds and returns a tree

My question is how after encoding a file - I can decode it according to project terms? Thanks for the help.

Comment: The encoding works properly. Encoding is done according to a dictionary per character.
Decoding also needs this dictionary. My question is how can I pass the dictionary to the decoder - without changing the signatures of the original functions.

My difficulty is to implement the decoder - without changing the 4 functions set by the lecturer. I can add as many functions as I want - as long as the structure remains the same - for the original 4 functions.

Comment: Since the Huffman trie is also required for decoding, you need to write it to the file together with the encoded message. Then you just need some logic on how to separate the encoded message from the trie in the decode method.

Comment: I agree with @Laugslander. I think you have only two options. 1. You can persist the tree by writing it to a file (either the same file as the encoded text, or a fixed named separate file), or 2. You can keep it in memory by adding an instance field. Keeping it in memory will of course make it impossible to decode later on.

Comment: Thanks for the help, I understood the explanation of the two of you, but how can I move a tree or map to a decoding file? And after that, how to know what belongs to the tree itself and what belongs to encoding?

Comment: I think the easiest way to differentiate between the two is to separate them into two files, like @Scratte suggested. One file for the message and one file for the Huffman trie. The easiest way to store the trie is to just serialize it on object level and write it to the file. The most efficient way to store the encoded message is to write bits to the file. Take a look at the Java BitSet class. In your current setup, you are writing Strings as bytes, which results in 16 bits per character ("0" or "1") in your encoded message.

Comment: There are many good tutorials on how to do the serialization (like [this from Baeldung](https://www.baeldung.com/java-serialization)) and since you're using the `HashMap` which implements the needed interface, this will likely be the easiest solution. If you were to implement it for a production environment, I'd be a bit cautious about serialization, but that's an entirely different topic :) If you want to keep the information in the same file, can you not separate the tree from the message by a newline with a special character?...

Comment: Thanks for the help, it works, but when I try to print the map - it shows me that the map is blank. I added another code - at the end of my question. I built as explained in the link you sent me, the code ran - but it shows that the map is blank, I can't understand why. Is the explanation listed in the question content clear? thanks for the help.

Comment: Thanks for the help, yes I added another detailed description of the question, the first function I ran inside the encoder - for it to copy the list into the file. And the second function I used in the decoder - to get the dictionary.

Comment: Thanks so much, you're right, my mistake.

Comment: Please consider doing a rollback when you've figured it all out. I would choose to Rollback to revision 6. You can do it by clicking on the "edited 1 hour ago" to see all the revisions made. Also post an Answer with only the things that you have **changed**, not the full code, so other users can see only what you had to do to make it work. Like added methods and changes to your main() method. If you added only one line to a method you can just mention: I added this line to methodname(), so that.. :) Let me know by writing @Scratte in your comment. Then I will clean up all these other comments.

Comment: Thank you for the help, of course, I'll make sure all the code is correct - and then I'll post the fix for the solution.

Answer (score 0):

I only built the first function that encodes the file. And auxiliary functions that help me encode - such as a function that counts a number of characters in the input file and a function that builds and returns a tree

After the forum help, I was able to move the tree from the encoder to the decoder. I added the tree into a file, and then created a new tree inside the decoder.

I add the code I wrote:
The code shows me that the tree I'm moving - is a blank tree - but it can't be - because the encoding works properly.

In order to move the map - I created 2 functions, readTreeFile and writeTreeFile .
One works in encoder - the map is copied to a file.
The second works the decoder - it pulls the map from the file.

```
public static Map<Character, String> readTreeFile (String[] output_names)
{
    Map<Character, String> codes = new HashMap<>();
    try {
        FileInputStream f = new FileInputStream(output_names[1]);
        ObjectInputStream s = new ObjectInputStream(f);
        codes = (HashMap<Character, String>) s.readObject();
        s.close();
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return codes;
}
public static void writeTreeFile (Map<Character, String> codes , String[] output_names)
{
    try {
        FileOutputStream f = new FileOutputStream(output_names[1]);
        ObjectOutputStream s = new ObjectOutputStream(f);
        s.writeObject(codes);
        s.close();
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```